# Is it possible to silently update shapes?

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I've created a small invoicing system in Excel, which utilizes macros in VBA. The system's navigation includes a digital clock, displaying the time in the HH:MM:SS format:

[image]

The clock is simply a drawn rectangle with text and is simply a U.I element which isn't used for anything other than visual appearance. It is updated every second via a recursive VBA function:

```
Sub updateTime()
    If (Not ActiveSheet.Name = "srcFacilities" And Not ActiveSheet.Name = "srcAnimals" And Not ActiveSheet.Name = "attrs") Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("timeRec")).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Format(Time, "hh:mm:ss")
    End If
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "updateTime"
End Sub
```

The system is run in full-screen without the Windows taskbar, hence the clock being a useful indicator of the time.

In testing, an issue that the users complained about was that the update of the clock caused Excel to momentarily freeze for around 1/4 a second & display the 'wait' cursor. This causes the users to become frustrated (understandably). The system itself is usable, but this issue is annoying so I'd like to get it resolved.

Is it possible to update the text inside the shape *without* Excel temporarily freezing on every update?

I tried changing the shape to a text box and updating with `ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("timeRecTest").Text = Format(Time, "hh:mm:ss")`, but that yielded the same result.

Comment: What if you added `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the start, then turned to `True` at the end?  I'm trying to think of ways to speed up a sub you use every second. Hmm...  Is there a purpose to having the clock *inside* the spreadsheet, instead of just using the system clock or something? Are you using the time in any way, or is it simply for the users to see?  Perhaps a sentence or two on *why* there's a clock might help, as there may be another way to do what it is you want done.

Comment: @BruceWayne It's simply for users to see, it's not used for anything other than a visual element within the U.I. I tried your suggestion, and it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Since you're using the current time (`Now`), why not just have a message box at the start that says like "Please be aware of the time!"?  If they're on Windows anyways, the clock is on the taskbar.  I'd have a think on whether having a dynamic clock in the spreadsheet itself is worth the effort.  Perhaps an alternative is to update it every ten minutes or so?

Comment: @BruceWayne Updated my question. Essentially the system is run in full-screen without the Windows taskbar being visible, so the clock is useful. For now I've modified it to update once a minute and only show HH:MM, but I'm still interested to see if there's a solution to this (it'll also help others in a similar situation).

Comment: Ah okay - I'm trying to think of some more suggestions.  Quick clarification - this sub is running the whole time the users are in Excel, correct? So it's literally just a clock that updates every second, always running while users work in Excel?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yeah, that exactly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101923/discussion-between-brucewayne-and-cybermonkey).

Comment: Excel VBA is single threaded so I don't think there's much you can do. Perhaps write an ActiveX control that sits on the sheet?